# Periodic and improper integral

Tags: real-analysis

> If function is continuous $f: R \to R$ such that $f(t) \le Ke^{at}$ for all $t \ge 0$ and for some constant $K>0$ and $a$ in real numbers. If $f(t)=f(t+T)$
>   Prove that: $$\int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-st}\ \mathrm dt=\frac1{1-e^{-sT}}\int_0^T f(t)e^{-st}\ \mathrm dt$$

I'm completely lost. Any ideas? I don't know how to got from $0$ to infinity on left side, to $0$ to $T$ on right one.

Comment: Expand $\dfrac{1}{1-e^{-sT}}$ into a geometric series.

Comment: split the integral into many pieces 0 to T, T to 2T,... then see if you can get some summations similar to geometric series. You might need to substitute something.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$\int_0^\infty f(t) e^{-st} \, dt = \sum \limits_{n = 0}^\infty \int_{nT}^{(n + 1)T} f(t) e^{-st} \, dt$$